# Chrome dev tools pauses on exceptions in blackboxed script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, exception, google-chrome-devtools

I have a JavaScript file that I have blackboxed in the Chrome developer tools and I have the debugger set to pause on uncaught exceptions.  However, the dev tools continues to pause on uncaught exceptions in the blackboxed JS file (see screenshot below).  Is this a Chrome bug?  Or is there an additional step required to make Chrome stop pausing on uncaught exceptions in blackboxed scripts?

[image]

According to https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing :

> What happens when you blackbox a script?
>
> Exceptions thrown from library code will not pause (if Pause on
> exceptions is enabled)

So this seems either like a bug, or I'm overlooking something obvious.

Comment: Looks like this is still a problem, as of Oct 1 2015: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=538447

Comment: It's still a problem on Apr 1 2015 in Chrome v49.0.2623.110 m

Comment: Also it's strange that adding script to blackbox via context menu does not set flag 'blackbox scripts' to true in devtools settings, just adds pattern.

Comment: Seems to be working in Chrome Canary, so hopefully this will get fixed soon.

Comment: not working in my Canary. I know this used to work but its broken again

Comment: still a problem, please google-guys and girls. Fix this.

Comment: Please post to this thread once it's been fixed.

Comment: Just tried. Still a bug as of Chrome 57.

Comment: Still a problem in 70.0.3538.7 (Nov '18) :(

Comment: 72.0.3626.121 seems to behave well.

Comment: Still the problem: 73.0.3683.75

Comment: Still a problem for me in 79.0.3945.130. Anyone find a fix?

Answer (score 9):

This issue is sadly not resolved as of 70.0.3538.77. Filed this [Chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=906435). The fun part? Dev Tools itself says it shouldn't stop on exceptions from blackboxed scripts - while being stopped in a blackboxed script

[image: Dev Tools clearly describing it shouldn't be where it actually is at the moment]

Answer (score 2):

This issue is fixed for me with version 56.0.2924.87.

If I blackbox a script with this version, the debugger does not stop anymore on a throw statement even when"pauses on caught exceptions" is checked.